# How to get data fron beanclass in springMVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How to get data from beanclass in springMVC?
I am trying but i got an error.

In Spring MVC I didnt get data from bean class

This is my bean class

```
    public class EmailBean
    {
        private Long id;
        private String from;
        private String to;
        private String subject;
        private String content;
        private String status;

        //getter and setter
    }
```

This is my Email sender

```
    public class EmailSender extends Thread
    {
        private EmailBean eb;

        public EmailBean getEb()
        {
            return eb;
        }

        public void setEb(EmailBean eb)
        {
            this.eb = eb;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            sendSingleEmail(eb);
        }

        public static void sendSingleEmail(EmailBean eb)
        {

            System.out.println(eb.getTo());
            System.out.println(eb.getSubject());
            System.out.println(eb.getContent());

        }
    }
```

This is my main class

```
    public class TestMail {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                EmailBean eb=new EmailBean();
                eb.setFrom("xxx@gmail.com");
                eb.setTo("yyyyy@gmail.com");
                eb.setSubject("Testing Email Subject");
                eb.setContent("Testing Email Content");
                eb.setId(1L);
                eb.setStatus("100");

                EmailSender es=new EmailSender();

                es.start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
```

When I run this TestMail it wont work why? I git an error

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.candidjava.springmvc.service.EmailSender.sendSingleEmail(EmailSender.java:36)
        at com.candidjava.springmvc.service.EmailSender.run(EmailSender.java:30)
```

Comment: Are you autowiring the beans? Null means that you are missing a reference to the right object.

Comment: Because you aren't setting anything. Also how is this spring related as there is nothing Spring related in your question .

Comment: there is no Spring in this, you are having a NullPointerException cause your EmailBean was never initialized.

Comment: @Lore i couldnt get it .I need when i call EmailSender from TextEmail I dint get -- sysout why?

Comment: @Rafik I set the beanvalues inside TestMail when i call EmailSender from TextEmail I dint get -- sysout

Comment: I think you'd have to start by looking into dependency injection and Spring tutorials. More issues will come on the way if you don't know exactly how the framework works. Just to put you on the right way, read about annotated and autowired beans.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple mistake you made in main method, before starting the thread just call the setter method to set the EmailBean information, find the below correct code

```
 public class TestMail {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            EmailBean eb=new EmailBean();
            eb.setFrom("xxx@gmail.com");
            eb.setTo("yyyyy@gmail.com");
            eb.setSubject("Testing Email Subject");
            eb.setContent("Testing Email Content");
            **eb.setId(1L);**
            eb.setStatus("100");

            EmailSender es=new EmailSender();
            es.setEb(eb);
            es.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

If you are new to spring mvc just try some simple [spring hello world example](http://java.candidjava.com/tutorial/Spring-mvc-hello-world-example.htm) to understand the basic